# How to count the number of number-based characters in an input field?

Tags: javascript, html, validation, input, user-input

I can get the count of all characters in a string like `e.target.value.length`. But how do I do this only for number-based characters inside a string? For example, for a string like "123-abc", how can I write an expression that would output the number-based character count to be `3` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace all non-digits with the empty string first:

```
str.replace(/\D+/g, '').length
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use regex to count the number of (single) matched digits:

```js
const input = "123-abc";
const re = /\d{1}/g
console.log(input.match(re).length);
```